# Is it necessary to call Camera.stopPreview() before MediaRecorder.start()?

Tags: android, android-camera, video-capture

I am having a basic Camera application using MediaRecorder. Application previews the video on TextureView and when button is clicked it starts recording. I works on most mobile phones, but on some specific device, underlying OMX fails:

```
(40b1df38)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/OMXCameraAdapter/OMXCameraAdapter.cpp:2176 UseBuffersPreview - Exiting function UseBuffersPreview because of ret 0 eError=80001018
```

and in consequence, preview freezes and recording fails.

I found that this is most likely caused when Camera object is still previewing, while MediaRecorder object start recording. When I call mCamera.stopPreview() before starting recording, it works. Therefore, I have following questions:
1. Why is call to mCamera.stopPreview() necessary on some devices, and not on others?
2. How can the recorded video be still previewed, if stopPreview() on Camera object is called, but MediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay() was not?

Below I present some code:

```
public boolean startRecording() throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
    if (!mRecordingStarted) {

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview(); // !!! without this recording fails on some devices!
            mCamera.unlock();
            mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);                mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
            mMediaRecorder.setProfile(mCamProfile);

            //mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());

            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mCaptureFile);
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            mMediaRecorder.start();
            mRecordingStarted = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mMediaRecorder.release();
            mCamera.lock();
            Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }
    return mRecordingStarted;
}


private void startPreview() throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
    if (mCamera == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
    mCamProfile = getConfiguredProfile();
    mVideoSize = getBestPreviewSize(mCamProfile, parameters);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(mVideoSize.width, mVideoSize.height);
    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY);

    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mPreview.getSurfaceTexture());
    mCamera.startPreview();
}
```